# Stored Procedure in MSSQL for joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a Stored Procedure to authenticate login.

I have two tables which will hold the data table structure given as below.

`Table : UserMaster`

```
Userid  Password  IsActive
1111    xyz        1
2222    abc        0
```

`Table : Userdetailes`

```
Userid   Status  StartDate    EndDate
1111     1       2015-08-01   2015-08-24
2222     0       2015-08-01   2015-08-10
```

this is how the data is stored in two tables

I want to write a stored procedure to view data from using join

Comment: just use a simple select query based on your business logic and if the query returns results you can allow the user to enter , or else just use an output parameter to return value based on business logic. And the best idea is join both tables based on userid and check the business conditions

Comment: could you help me with the sample as in how it could be done keeping this scenarios in mind

Comment: please tag to one db , are you using mysql or sql server ???

Comment: select c.* from (select a.* from UserSubscription a
inner join 
(select * from UserMaster where IsActive=1)b
on a.UserId=b.Userid)c
where c.Status=1
and c.Startdate=c.Enddate    use this sample query and if you need to include any business logic more add to it

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspauth]
   @LoginId        NVARCHAR(30)
  ,@ActiveStatus INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN TRY

        --1 - Both Active, 2 - User InActive & Package Active, 3 - User Inactive & Package Inactive , 4 - Not authosrised
        DECLARE @Username VARCHAR(40), @isAct Bit,@stat Bit   

        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UserSet where UserID = @LoginId)
          BEGIN
               RAISERROR('login does not exist',16,1)
               RETURN;
          END
        SELECT @Username = ISNULL(UserID,0), @isAct  = ISNULL(IsActive, 0) from UserSet where UserID = @LoginId)
        Select @stat = ISNULL([status],0) from Subscription where UserID = @LoginId 
                                                   and (DateOfStart <= CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) or DateOfStart is NULL) 
                                                   and (DateOfEnd   >= Cast(GETDATE() as DATE) or DateOfEnd   is NULL)

         IF (@isAct = 1 AND @stat = 1)  --1 - Both Active
           BEGIN
             SET @ActiveStatus  = 1;
           END
        ELSE IF (@isAct = 0 AND @stat = 1) -- 2 - User InActive & Package Active
           BEGIN
             SET @ActiveStatus  = 2;
           END
        ELSE IF (@isAct = 1 AND @stat = 0) -- 3 - User Active & Package Inactive
           BEGIN
             SET @ActiveStatus  = 3;
           END
        ELSE IF (@isAct = 0 AND @stat = 0) -- 4 - Not authosrised
           BEGIN
             SET @ActiveStatus  = 4;
           END

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRAN
            END

        EXEC uspProcErrorLog    
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: @LearningDB: if this was the solution, please consider accepting the answer. To do so, click the tick mark to the left of the answer, so that it turns green. This is how we indicate a question has been resolved here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The last `if else` code block can be simplified with `case expression`:

```
set @status = case when @isAct = 1 and @stat = 1 then 1
                   when @isAct = 0 and @stat = 1 then 2
                   when @isAct = 1 and @stat = 0 then 3
                   when @isAct = 0 and @stat = 0 then 4 
              end

return @status
```